# AJAX Refresh of SimpleXML PHP Causing Error

Tags: php, ajax, simplexml

I have the following in a php file:

> ```
> // Loading the XML file
> $xml = simplexml_load_file("external/kcyt.xml");
> echo "<h5>Now Playing:</h5>";
> foreach($xml->children() as $audio)
> {
>     echo "<h5>Artist : ".$audio->artist." <br />";
>     echo "Title : ".$audio->title." </h5><br />";
> } ?>
> ```

When I try to use AJAX on it with various methods found here and elsewhere, as soon as the AJAX refreshes it throws an error. Can anyone give me a method to refresh the div containing the include for this file that will not cause an error? Seems that simplexml doesn't like being called a second time for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you refresh it?

Comment: Also, please post the exact error you see - even if you can't make head nor tail of it, someone else might know exactly what would cause it.